# How to block access from the tor user

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am a Japanese university students.I studied the Tor.
I want to block tor users to access the web server.Is there a way to block access other than to block the exit node of the tor.

Comment: No. Blocking Tor exit nodes is the only way to block Tor users. In all honesty, there's really no reason to block Tor users anyway, since your website can be attacked with or without Tor.

Comment: Can you please share some more details: why do you want to block Tor users and what kind of website and processes on it you want to put aside from Tor?

Comment: Supplement:　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　I learned that a malicious user will come to attack using the tor. However, it is difficult to block to find the only malicious user. So I thought trying to block the tor user. Block of only malicious user is the future challenges.

Comment: A malicious user will also come to attack using the normal Internet. Are you going to block the Internet user too?

Answer (score 1):

Tor is *just* a network instrument, there are *many* of them... The crime exists *inside malicious user's mind*, and it has no relation to *any tool he uses*. So - blocking Tor won't help you a bit, if your task is to protect the website from malicious activities. My good advice to you - forget about 1990-years AtGuard tactiks with a blocklists in txt files: it does not work at all nowdays. Focus on hardening and guarding your website itself, and it will work fine *regardless of the connection methods* used by user.